# Why this function is strictly concave?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My book says that this $f(x,y,z)=-e^{x+y+z}+x-y^{2}-z^{2}$ is strictly concave but it also requires to deduce the concavity with a proposition that says :

If $X\subseteq R^{n}$ is a convex set, and $f_{i}$ for $i=1,2,3,...,m$ are $m$ concave functions and $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{m}$ are $m$ not negative numbers then the function $f:X \to R$ defined by the sum of the $f_{i}$ each multiplied by the $a_{i}$ coefficient is concave. $f$ is strictly concave if at least one of the $f_{i}$ is strictly concave and the correspondent coefficient $a_{i}>0$ .

So I can divide the function in three parts :

$f(x,y,z)=-e^{x+y+z}$

$f(x,y,z)=x$

$f(x,y,z)=-y^{2}-z^{2}$

But each of this function is not strictly concave…So why the function is strictly concave? Are there other simple results to use for deducing the strinct concavity?

Comment: Is this $f(x,y,z)=-e^{x+y+z}$ strictly concave?

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's not clear.

Comment: It should be just concave because it is a composition of a strictly concave and a not strictly concave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful for this problem that the (strict) concavity of a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to its (strict) concavity on every one-dimensional affine subspace---that is, on every line.

Now, $-y^2 - z^2$ is strictly concave on every line not parallel to the line generated by $(1, 0, 0)$, and so by the proposition $f(x, y, z)$ is strictly concave on such lines. Also, $-e^{x + y + z}$ is strictly concave on every line not parallel to the plane $x + y + z = 0$, so again by the proposition $f(x, y, z)$ is strictly concave here. Because the line generated by $(1, 0, 0)$ and the plane defined by $x + y + z = 0$ together generate $\mathbb{R}^3$, every line falls into one of these two classes, so this argument is enough.

Comment: Why is  '$-y^2 - z^2$ is strictly concave on every line not parallel to the line generated by $(1, 0, 0)$'  true?

Comment: Identify such a line with $\mathbb{R}$ by an affine parameterization and look at $f$. You'll find a non-zero quadratic of negative leading coefficient if you picked a line along which $y$ and $z$ are non-constant, and a constant otherwise.